# Why does Wong laugh for the first time at the end of the movie?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange-2016

Dr. Strange believes Wong lacks a sense of humor and never laughs.

However, at the end of the movie, after Dr. Strange made his bargain and cast out Kaecilius and his minions, Wong [laughed like a drain](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/224000.html).

What's so funny in this?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You have to pay attention to the dialog throughout the movie. When Steven Strange first discovers the Eye of Agamotto, he reads an ancient manuscript which instructs him on how to manipulate time. Wong and Mordo rush in and stop him, and Wong angrily tells Strange that his actions could have had serious consequences (creating a time loop, or altering the future in an unwanted way). He asks Strange why he didn't heed the warnings in the book. Strange says:

> They really should put the warnings at the beginning of spells

Now, skip to the end of the movie, where Kaecilius and his minions have just been dragged into eternal torment by Dormammu. Dr. Strange says:

> You really should’ve stolen the whole book because the warnings come after the spells.

Wong obviously finds the irony in this funny, thus why he laughs for the first time in the movie.

Comment: Not just this, but Mister Doctor (which is Strange, but who am I to judge?) says earlier in the movie "people used to think that I was funny", to which Wong responds "did that work for you?". Also, there are other comments like "try me, Beyonce" in which Stephen is trying to make Wong laugh. So this is a running joke of Stephen trying to make Wong laugh but failing, and then making a Schwarzenegger-style comment and causing Wong to laugh unintentionally.

Comment: @Daevin It's not "did that work for you?", but "did they work for you?"

Comment: @KinzleB I believe you are correct. My bad.

Comment: Also, the only "evidence" that Wong never laughed at all was Dr Strange's remark. Maybe he did laugh sometimes, off screen.

Answer (score 26):

Another possibility that has been raised on [sites like TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Fridge/DoctorStrange2016) is that it's about master-subordinate systems, and a callback to an earlier exchange where Strange points out that people usually laugh at his jokes, and Wong queries whether those people are subordinates. Strange's prior jokes are uttered with the expectation of laughs. This one is spontaneous, and after he and Wong are on an even footing as friends and comrades.

Comment: Or, now that Strange has demonstrated his sorcerous mastery, Wong now feels obligated to laugh at his jokes.

Comment: They do make a point that Strange is not yet the Sorcerer Supreme, so not yet. :)